# Proving properties of determinants.

Tags: determinant

I'm trying to prove the properties of determinants. I have observed some patterns, which I have verified to be true from the internet. For example, each term in the expansion of a determinant contains one element each from every row and column. Hence, there are $n!$ terms in the expansion of an $n$-determinant.

I'm trying to prove other properties of determinants like you could expand it along any row or column of your choice. I'm pretty certain that expanding along any row or column, one would get the same terms. However, I haven't been able to prove that the signs of the terms too will be the same.

How do I process from here? Could anyone point me to an internet link which contains proofs of the properties of determinants with the above intuition in mind? Most "proofs" that I come across just verify said properties for a $3\times 3$ matrix. It is really not satisfying.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can find these facts in most introductory linear algebra texts, such Gilbert Strang "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" or David Poole's "Linear Algebra and its Applications" (I like the presentation in this book), and I'd recommend looking at these instead. There are some in ["Linear Algebra Done Wrong"](http://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html), but I dislike this book.

Theres also the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) article.